# Is 'folk' a politically correct substitute for 'people'?

Tags: synonyms, word-usage, political-correctness

***Edit:*** Comments so far have focused on the speech of politicians. While this discussion is interesting, and desired when relevant, I am more concerned with use in activist communities. I believe the connotation is different: unlike politicians, these people are not trying to sound more 'folksy' or 'of the people'.

I often hear *folk* used in leftist and activist communities. The word choice seems ideologically motivated, a more politically correct synonym for *people* — just as one would say 'differently-abled' instead of 'disabled' or 'latina' instead of 'hispanic' — but I can't determine any need for the substitution. Is *people* offensive? The most common use is in 'black folk', but also 'white folk', 'brown folk', 'queer folk', etc.

My fundamental question is this: **Why is *folk* used more often in activist communities?**

I recognize that I don't have hard evidence to demonstrate the truth of the phenomenon. I'm not sure what evidence I could provide. So let's all play together and assume it is true?

I can imagine two answers to this question.

1. ***Folk* is a politically correct substitute for *people*.** Why, then, is *people* offensive, and *folk* not?
2. **The word choice is not ideologically but historically motivated.** *Folk* is historically common in the black community. As non-black people interact with black vocabulary, they assimilate (either naturally, or because of a false believe in #1). As listening-oriented black/non-black interaction is more common in activist spaces, the use of *folk* has spread quickest in activist communities.

These are, however, simply unfounded hypotheses.

Comment: ***Folks vs people***: 
 
Recently I was amused to hear Jon Stewart express bewilderment at George Bush’s continued use of the word folks in inappropriate contexts. This is one of many of the President’s peculiarities of speech that has bothered me for some time. Stewart was referring to this remark in the President’s July 4 speech:

"*Many of the spectacular car bombings and killings you see are as a result of al Qaeda — the very same folks that attacked us on September the 11th.”* http://www.dailywritingtips.com/folks-versus-people/

Comment: Interesting point. Almost the opposite phenomenon here.

Comment: ***Are Politicians Folking With Us? The overuse of ‘folks’ in today’s political rhetoric** 

*With the 2016 presidential election around the corner and candidates rolling up their sleeves for good old-fashioned town hall talks, there is one word we are bound to hear a lot: folks.
‘Folks’ has become a time honored tradition in politics. A way for stuffy, white, old men to seem a little more, well, folksy.*
http://randomnerds.com/are-politicians-folking-with-us-the-overuse-of-folks-in-todays-political-rhetoric/ - http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/21/magazine/folkwisdom.html?_r=0

Comment: Well *folk*'s German root [*volk*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volk_(German_word)) has a lot of historical precedence in political movement, most notably in Nazism. In German it connotes a spirit of a big society and of common history particularly of before the German Republic and of the Brothers Grimm's *Folk*lore. Perhaps these feelings of traditionalism and of being in touch with the people are being hinted at even if accidentally in modern politics.

Comment: "People" got its negative connotation in race relations by speakers saying "*you* people" (e.g., "*You people* are always...").  The phrase "you people" was and is perceived as being racist and objectifying.  As a result, in any kind of argument about race or bigotry, it has become kind of a thing for those who feel racially prejudiced against to protest the first time someone says "people" by saying, "People?!  People?!" as if the word is inherently racist even without the "you" beforehand.  As a result, politicians and the PC have veered from using "people" altogether, thus "folks."

Comment: As in @Josh61 link stated _Folks generally suggests a certain warmth and “down home” flavor._ Which is probably something activist communities go for. Because they need that sense of belonging together.

Comment: @Unrelated To my knowledge folk is not a 'politically correct' version of people, if is merely a synonym and one that is popular in Left and activist circles because of its sounding more casual

Comment: 'Differently abled' is actually dispreferred among the disabled community. @BladorthinTheGrey *Volk* is the German *cognate* of *folk*, ultimately from the same root. While *Volk* suggests large society to Germans, to English (and American) ears *folk* sounds rural, laid-back and - well, *folksy*.

Comment: @Nothingatall Yes I agree with you *folk* does sound more laid-back, which politicians and activists are probably implying

Comment: I think it's a mistake to treat _folk_ and _folks_ as if they are interchangeable terms. In southeast Texas, where I grew up in the 1960s, black and white speakers alike always used the plural noun form _folks_. Saying "Howdy, folk" would have been as tin-eared and foreign-sounding as saying (in that part of Texas)  _you-all_ instead of _y'all_. But people not to the manner born often and understandably fail to grasp the nuances of genuine down-home speech as spoken in any particular region; and in attempting to replicate it, they may commit such blunders as using _folk_ in place of _folks_.

Comment: @SvenYargs I agree, and I think that is misdirection occurring in these comments. I am interested in 'folk' as a 'folk', not as a corruption of 'folks', whereas I think some of this discussion has focused on politicians' use of 'folks' and 'folk'-for-'folks'

Comment: One interesting early example of _folk_ as _folk_ is W.E.B. Du Bois's [_The Souls of Black Folk_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Souls_of_Black_Folk) (1903), an examination of the social, political, and spiritual condition of black Americans at the beginning of the twentieth century. According the Wikipedia article on Du Bois, he was born in Massachusetts and his parents' families were Northerners going back at least two generations. But he attended college in Tennessee for three years (before attending Harvard), so he did have direct experience of contemporaneous Southern black English.

Answer (score 2):

A POB issue, but the following ***[extract](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/21/magazine/folkwisdom.html?_r=0)*** from the New York Times offers some good points:

> ***Folks is a homogeneous social group as contrasted with the individual or with a selected class,”***  according to Webster. It originated from the Old English “folc,” or “people,” and expanded in the 19th century to incorporate the concept of “folklore,” which included a sense of passing along a common narrative.

Early usage of "folks" in politics:

> ***“Folks” made occasional political appearances in the early 20th century, often in the form of “just folks” — “just” underscoring the attempt at humility.***  In a Times account of President Warren G. Harding’s 1923 trip to Denver, he was commended for his accessible manner. “He was ‘just folks’ and people liked his ways,” The Times concluded. A clip from 1932 described F.D.R.’s campaigning in New York for the future governor Herbert Lehman. “All was neighborly, homely, informal; from dairy farmer to governor, from garden trickster to lieutenant governor,” The Times reported. “Everybody was just folks.”

More recent usages and current connotation of "folks":

> ***In recent decades, “folks” has become more of a politician’s crutch.*** As Favreau noted, it solves the problem of how best to refer to any collection, assembly or generic mass.

Alternatives abound but can be problematic:

> ***“The American people” was an old standby, as in “the American people are sick and tired of so-and-so.” But this can seem a little presumptuous, especially as the population has grown more diverse, globalized and splintered.*** “The People” (as in “power to the people” or “we the people”) enjoyed an uprising in the ’60s and ’70s. Backlash ensued: “Unfortunately, I Do Not Identify With the People,” said a headline over a 1972 Times column by Kathryn R. Bloom. “The People is the little guy. The People is honest. Decent. Sincere. Simple, even. The People is fed up.”
>
> ***The People*** — evidenced by its capitalization — was at least meant to be a term of collective empowerment. The People is an awesome, singular force; as opposed to “the little guy,” which was Harry Truman’s favorite, or the “common man,” preferred by F.D.R. Today, neither would suit the inflated self-involvement of baby-boomers, let alone millennials.

Comment: Is that last paragraph you or is the whole block quoted text one source?

Answer (score -2):

Looking into the etmology of the orgin of "folks".

It is a clear term of segregation.

It originates during the Germanic Uprising and eventual downfall of the German Monarchy.

It was a term to for "common people" aka peasant's army.

During such a tumultuous time where the nobles looked down on their people.

I firmly believe it was not used in an endearing way. It was used in a way to segregate classes and their own countrymen. Whenever I hear someone use the word folks, it seems to always come from someone in a position where they exercise legitimate power, vs authentic power. ( Gary Zukav explains further the difference between legitimate power vs authentic power in his book, Seat of the Soul.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is nonsense. _Folk_ goes back to Old English. I think you are talking about how the German word Volk was weaponised by the Nazis: it has nothing to do with the English work _folk_.